# Scanner. Как из System.in пропустить ввод начинающийся с букв, а читать ввод начинающийся с цифр?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, scanner

В System.in для Scanner ввожу данные через Enter: 1 2 3 a1 4. Хочу получить сумму чисел, т.е. 10. Слово "а1" нужно игнорировать. Как это сделать, к тому же без обработки исключений?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```java
double sum = Stream.of(new Scanner(System.in).nextLine().split("\\s+")).filter(s -> {
            try { 
                Double.parseDouble(s); 
                return true; 
            } catch (Exception e) { 
                return false; 
            }
        }).mapToDouble(Double::valueOf).sum();
```

**1)** Считываем строчку `new Scanner(System.in).nextLine()`;
**2)** Разделяем её по пробелам и превращаем в массив `split("\\s+")`.
**3)** Создаём стрим `Stream.of()`.
**4)** Отсеиваем строки, которые не представляют из себя числа `filter()`.
**5)** Превращаем каждый элемент стрима в число и меняем тип стрима, чтобы можно было найти его сумму `mapToDouble(Double::valueOf)`.
**6)** Получаем сумму всех элементов стрима `sum()`.

Если уж вы хотите без исключений в методе `filter()`, его можно записать так:

```
.filter(s -> s.matches("[-+]?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?(?:[eE][-+]?\\d+)?"))
```

---

Есть и другой вариант:

```java
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\S)[-+]?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?(?:[eE][-+]?\\d+)?(?!\\S)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(new Scanner(System.in).nextLine());
double sum = 0;
while(matcher.find())
    sum += Double.parseDouble(matcher.group());
```

Здесь с помощью регулярного выражения из строки ищутся числовые подстроки.

---

Хотя самым простым и быстрым вариантом будет такой:

```java
double sum = 0;
for (String s : new Scanner(System.in).nextLine().split("\\s+"))
    try {
        sum += Double.parseDouble(s);
    } catch (Exception ignored) {}
```

Но вы почему-то не хотите обрабатывать исключения, хотя в принципе они здесь и не обрабатываются, они игнорируются, но это, скорее, придирка к словам.

---

Ну можно ещё каким-то таким способом сделать, но это никуда не годится, потому что надо в конце `break` писать.

```java
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
double sum = 0;
while(true) {
    String s = scanner.next();
    if(s.equals("break"))
        break;
    if(s.matches("[-+]?\\d+(.\\d+)?([eE][-+]?\\d+)?"))
        sum += Double.parseDouble(s);
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Разве нельзя использовать регулярное выражение в методе useDelimetr() для Scanner чтобы отсеить все слова? По-моему регулярное выражение должно быть другим...

Comment: Регулярное выражение правильное, но рассчитано на double, если вам нужен только int, его можно записать так: `[-+]?\\d+`. С delimeter сделать не получается из-за того, что строка может содержать такие подстроки: `a1`. Гораздо лучше использовать `split()`.

Comment: То есть как бы можно с delimeter сделать, но проблема делиметра в том, что сканер не читает последнюю подходящую подстроку в строке, это можно исправить, дописав в конце делиметра `|`, но тогда `hasNext()` всегда будет `true`, и в таком случае нужно точно знать количество подходящих подстрок.

Comment: @IgorKhilkevich я ответил на ваш вопрос?

Comment: я не до конца проверил, т.к решил эту задачу по другому, с помощью стандартных методов класса Scanner.

Comment: @IgorKhilkevich каким образом вы решили задачу?

Comment: код без try:
```while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            if (scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
                d1 += scanner.nextDouble();
            } else {
                scanner.next();
            }
        }```

Comment: @IgorKhilkevich `scanner.hasNext()` всегда истинно, если вы читаете из консоли. Каким образом вы произвели остановку сканера? Через `ctrl + D`?

Comment: да, все верно, через `ctrl + D`

Comment: @IgorKhilkevich не нравится мне такой подход. Я предлагал варианты без этого.